# msysgit large installation size

Tags: msysgit

I installed (extracted) [msysgit portable](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases) (PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20150319.7z)

The compressed archive is 23 MB, but once extracted the contents take up 262 MB. This is mostly due to the git command binaries (under 'libexec\git-core'). Almost all of the binaries are identical, they just have different names.

Why did the developers build the project like this? I suppose they need an executable for each command to support the CLI on windows cmd.exe.

But isn't there a way to avoid having ~100 identical binaries, each 1.5 MB in size (ex: using batch files)?

Comment: why the downvote? Please explain. BTW I don't care about the installation size. I am just trying to understand the developers' motivations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did the developers build the project like this? I suppose they
>   need an executable for each command to support the CLI on windows
>   cmd.exe.

Under unixoid OSes, you can have symbolic links to another file that behave *exactly* like the original file; if you do that for your executable, your executable can look into `argv[0]` to find out how it was called. That's a very common trick for many programs.

Under Windows, and especially without installers, it's (to my knowledge) impossible to get the same behaviour out of your file system -- there's just no symbolic link equivalent. Especially when you consider that programs that are meant to run from USB drives have to cope with ancient filesystems such as FAT32!

Thus, the executables simply were copied over. Same functionality, more storage. However, on a modern machine that you'd run windows on, you really don't care about 200MB give or take for such a versatile tool such as `git`.

In conclusion: the developers had no choice here; since windows (though having some posix abstraction layer) has no proper filesystem support for symbolic links, that was the only good way to port this unix-originating program. You either shouldn't care or use an OS that behaves better in that respect. I'd recommend the latter, but OS choices often aren't made freely...

Comment: Windows Vista and up support symbolic links, but you need to run as admin (correct me if I'm wrong). And that would still leave out Windows XP.

Comment: And would subvert the idea of the application being "portable" ie. not needing any administrator privileges to be installed somewhere. Also, to stress that, FAT32, as still commonly found on USB drives, can not support symlinks.

Comment: Would it be possible to have 100 tiny identical exe's that just link to a single large DLL? That way you could name the exe's differently and `argv[0]` would work as expected.

Comment: @bouvierr: yes, but that would require a restructuring of the source code/build structure just to support a wicked platform